How do I set the Excel Colors Theme from C# (e.g. using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel)?
We have a corporate colour scheme that is automatically included on ever user machine as a Custom Color collection in Page Layout > Colors > [customNameHere].
I have an add-in that (as part of a load of other tasks) needs to do some configuration of any arbitrary Excel Workbook the user chooses - effectively a "Setup" button for a given Workbook. Is there any way to look for the presence of this [customNameHere] Color Theme from my C# code, and then set the Workbook to use that theme if it exists?
I have tried searching the internet for the beginning of an answer, but am unsure quite what to search for!
I am currently using a couple of methods from ExcelDNA for performance-critical interactions with Excel, but mostly just using the Interop assembly for tasks like this, that are low-frequency and not performance-critical.
Let's say I have set a reference to the Workbook object in question and want to look for the theme colour, I want something that looks like this:
using xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

[...]
xl.Workbook wb = // some code to set the Workbook object - too complex to include here

// What method do I use on wb object to, for example, set the theme to Grayscale, as this is one of the built-in themes that you will all have access to?
wb.???.???.??? = "Grayscale"

Presumably I would just wrap that code in a try statement for my corporate colour theme, to handle the case where it does not exist on a particular user machine for some reason.

using xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

xl.Workbook wb = // code to set the Workbook object

string customColorTheme = "[customNameHere]";

bool themeExists = false;
foreach (xl.Theme theme in wb.ThemeNames)
{
    if (theme.Name == customColorTheme)
    {
        themeExists = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (themeExists)
{
    xl.Worksheet activeSheet = (xl.Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;
    activeSheet.EnableThemeFont = true;
    activeSheet.EnableThemeFormatting = true;
    activeSheet.Theme = customColorTheme;
}
else
{
    // Handle the case where the custom color theme does not exist in the workbook
}

This code snippet iterates through the available themes in the workbook and checks if the custom color theme exists. If it does, it enables the theme font and formatting for the active worksheet and sets the theme to the custom color theme.

Thanks for a good and speedy reply, but I cannot see wb.ThemeNames - I am using .NET 4.8 (for ease of deployment in my organisation), so could that limit my options here?
Also, I am unsure why your example sets the properties on the ActiveSheet only? The setting I am targeting that I would do in the GUI is in Page Layout > Colors - this seems to be a Workbook property?
